# Show that the transformation w=z² is conformal at point z=1+i by finding the images of the lines y=x and x=1 which intersect at z=1+i.

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is:
Show that the transformation w=z² is conformal at point z=1+i by finding the images of the lines y=x and x=1 which intersect at z=1+i.

I am not sure how to proceed with this question. Please help.

Comment: A conformal map (locally) preserves angles, so you must show that the angle made by the lines $y=x$ and $x=1$ at the point $z=1+i$ is the same as the angle made by the image-lines of $y=x$ and $x=1$ under the map $w=z^2$ at the image of $z=1+i$; that is at the point $w=z^2=(1+i)^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Blake, got the answer. It seems like I need to practice more..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An analytic function $f(z)$ is conformal at a point $z=a$ if $f'(a)$ is non-zero. The given function $f(z)=z^2$ is analytic and $f'(1+i)$=$2(1+i)$ which is non-zero.